# why am I getting 404 from api post requests to node express app with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, api, express, nginx, post

I followed this tutorial to deploy my node express app on a digital ocean droplet using an nginx reverse proxy: https://lengstorf.com/code/deploy-nodejs-ssl-digitalocean/

The app serves static webpages, and only has one post request in the API.
It works fine when running locally, but when the code is running on the server submitting my basic form returns a 404.

I am very new to this, this is the first website I have tried to host. I havn't been able to find anything online that helps this specific issue, so let me know if I can provide any more details. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my Server code:

```
//App.js

var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const router = require('./routes/index');
const app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', router);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
    //res.render('error');

  res.json({
    message: err.message,
       error: err
  });
    console.error(err.message);

});

module.exports = app;
```

...

```
//index.js
const emailListApi = require('./EmailList');
const usersApi = require('./users');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('./../public/index.html', { title: 'mySite' });
});

router.use('/api/emailList', emailListApi);
router.use('/api/user', usersApi);



module.exports = router;
```

...

```
//EmailList.js
const options = require ('./options');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const fs = require( 'fs' );

router.post('/add', (req, res, next) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    if(!name || !email) {
        res.sendStatus(400);
        console.info('  Bad request - Request does not contain name or email');
    } else {
        const path = req.body.filePath ?
            options.assetsDir + req.body.filePath : options.emailList;
        if(!fs.existsSync(path)) {
            fs.writeFileSync(path);
        }
        const entry = '\n' + name + ' (' + email + ')';
        fs.appendFileSync(path, entry);
        console.info('  Added ' + name + ' (' + email + ') ' + ' to the distribution list');

        res.sendStatus(204);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the html for my form:

```
<!--contact.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <main>
        <form name="subForm" id="subscriptionForm" method="POST" action="/api/emailList/add" autocomplete="off">
            <div>
                <h2>Subscribe for updates:</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                    <input name="txtEmail" id="email" type="email">
                    <span>Please enter a valid email address.</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input name="txtName" id="name" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="subButt">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </main>
</div>
<script>
    const form = document.getElementById("subscriptionForm");
    if (form.addEventListener) { // addEventListener for chrome
        form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const xh = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xh.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xh.readyState == 4 && xh.status == 200) {
                    console.log("bitchin");
                }
            };
            xh.open("POST", "/api/emailList/add", true);
            xh.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            xh.send(JSON.stringify({
                email: form.email.value,
                name: form.name.value
            }));
        });
    } else if (form.attachEvent) { // attachEvent for IE
        form.attachEvent('onsubmit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const xh = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xh.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xh.readyState == 4 && xh.status == 200) {
                    console.log("bitchin");
                }
            };
            xh.open("POST", "/api/emailList/add", true);
            xh.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            xh.send(JSON.stringify({
                email: form.email.value,
                name: form.name.value
            }));
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my sites-enabled config file for nginx:

```
# HTTP -- redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    #Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name alphamated.com;

    # Use the Let's Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mySite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mySite.com/privkey.pem;

    #Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Arron. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Are you calling your application on port 80 or 443. I can see very different configurations for the two ports on your nginx config.

Comment: Hi Esteban, thanks for the response. All of my traffic should be directed through https using 443. I followed some templates and tutorials for my configuration, possibly without fully understanding them (newbie mistake lol), but my understanding is that those first few lines should redirect any http requests to https. If I try to go to the home page http:// alphamated.com it redirects to https:// alphamated.com, and my post request shows as https:// alphamated.com/api/emailList/add, but returns 404